# Implementation TL-Schema for Telegram API with java

Tags: java, code-generation, telegram, mtproto

I want to implement Telegram API layers with java.
I found TL-Schema for Telegram (Layer 71)
in this link : https://tjhorner.com/tl-schema/

Is there a code-generator automatically TL-Schema to Java classes?